# "Hot Network Questions" website icons scrambled

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, user-interface, hot-questions

I've noticed something weird with the HNQ icons:

[image: How is the "load average" interpreted in "top" output? Is it the same for all distributions?]

Now, while the question is on the "**U**nix and Linu**x**".SE, that icon is actually for "**U**ser E**x**perience".SE.

This is just a random sample, but about half of the HNQ has icons swapped (not necessarily with other websites listed in HNQ, and not necessarily in any pattern of swapping).

Comment: That's not the icon I see... They seem to be correct for me.

Comment: @Catija It's random, for example, after refreshing it a couple times, now I get the Workplace.SE icon on that HNQ.

Comment: I'm experiencing it too, as I reported in meta.stats; http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4268/why-am-i-seeing-the-se-network-icons-exchanged?noredirect=1#comment10479_4268
At first it seemed to happen only there, but then I noticed it also happened in other sites of the SE network too.

Answer (score 8):

We have a race condition where when we update the favicon sprite map (which happened earlier today for a new private beta launch), depending on which web server you're hitting, you could end up with new cachebreakers and old images if you visit a site during a prod build.

I'll ask around tomorrow to see what, if anything, we can do about that. AFAIK this didn't used to be a thing, but it seems to be happening pretty reliably to folks with every site we launch now.

Comment: Appears to have been solved today, I'm not seeing it anymore.

Comment: @Firebug there seem to be similar [bug report at MSO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/332639/839601), Oded marked it [meta-tag:status-completed]

Comment: @gnat Thanks for the heads up. Oded also posted on my question at meta.stats.SE