# Icons for some sites look like messed up in user profile

Tags: bug, design, profile-page

Icons for MSE, SO, Programmers look like messed up in user profile. Am I only one observing this?

Below is example screen shot showing messed up icons in [this user profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/811/shog9) to the left and as a reference the correct icons as they appear in [network profile for the same user](https://stackexchange.com/users/620/shog9?tab=accounts) to the right:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Comment: What browser? I'm not seeing this at all.

Comment: @bluefeet FF 48.0, MS Edge 11.545.10586.0, Chrome 52.0.2743.116 m, IE 11.545.10586.0 on Win10

Comment: ...though maybe [Puzzling icon](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/) for Programmers is okay, it can be a part of [new site name and scope](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/new-site-name) changes

Comment: Am I the only one who sees your image covering up the related and hot network questions on the right?  http://i.stack.imgur.com/weGk6.png

Comment: @zondo i observed similar effect with some browsers and OSes. I don't see it now, so you maybe tell your

Comment: I'm using Firefox 45.3.0 on Linux Mint 17.

Comment: @zondo is that the latest version you can use? I think my FF did something weird at version 47 and iirc 46. In the same time, Chrome and IE 11 worked well. It wasn't on Linux though

Comment: Interesting.  Firefox 47 doesn't have a problem for me.

Comment: Problem appears for me too. Favicons are selected based on y-index from [the icons "mega image"](https://cdn.sstatic.net/img/favicons-sprite16.png). Looks like SE have added another site somewhere in the list, which caused all the icons below it to shift 32 pixels, which means that affected sites appear as the icon 32 pixels below them in the "mega image". In the case of your screenshots, Puzzling.SE icon is 32 pixels below Programmers.SE.

Comment: wonder what could be a reasoning of idiots who voted this down. Evaluation of SE dev team in [duplicate target](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/283807/165773) suggests that there is indeed a bug, and my report has been posted 5 hours earlier than that meaning I didn't miss a dupe when posting and, which is even more interesting, as pointed in comments over there my issue persists after target dupe was reported as fixed. FWIW I managed to reproduce issue reported here from different computer at different provider, not to mention that @Adnan confirmed it in above comment. Meta voting as usual...

Comment: ...FWIW icons seem to be messed just the same in my inbox and achievements dropdowns in my [meta-tag:top-bar]. Stack Exchange dropdown at top-bar shows icons correctly though

Comment: When icons get messed up, it means SE updated the Sprites (usually when a private beta is launched, or when a site gets a new design), and forgot to kick their cache. It happened [over](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/281995/) [three](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/283497/) [times](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/283807/) in the last 20 days, and surely this isn't the last time.

Comment: @ShadowWizard 6 hours ago [they said they kicked the cache](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/283809/165773) but the issue seems to persist

Comment: @gnat try hard reloading on your side, clear cache, etc.

Comment: @ShadowWizard clearing cache and hard reload in Firefox didn't do the trick, messed icons are still there. Top-bar is particularly strange: here at MSE it shows me inbox and achievements with correct icons but at SO and Programmers these are messed up

Comment: @gnat OK, let's debug. Browse directly to http://cdn.sstatic.net/img/favicons-sprite16.png?v=aeb093174d91 and post a screenshot of the Response Headers you get. I'll compare this with the headers I get. (It's working fine for me.)

Comment: @Adam wrong dupe. This is the actual duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/281519/site-icons-misplaced (it's most likely another Varnish cache issue)

Comment: @gnat sorry, looks like it's not on your side indeed. I'm pretty sure the Varnish cache (whatever this is) needs a purge again, see [this comment by Oded](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/281519/site-icons-misplaced#comment914651_281519).

Comment: @ShadowWizard I could not understand what FF shows me at this URL but curl -I shows `HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: max-age=604800
Content-Type: image/png
Last-Modified: Tue, 23 Aug 2016 15:54:02 GMT
ETag: "692079256fdd11:0"
Content-Length: 64518
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Date: Wed, 24 Aug 2016 13:03:18 GMT
Via: 1.1 varnish
Age: 75960
Connection: keep-alive
X-Served-By: cache-bma7030-BMA
X-Cache: HIT
X-Cache-Hits: 4
X-Timer: S1472043798.844581,VS0,VE0
Vary: Accept-Encoding`

Comment: curl isn't good, most likely the browser is getting something else. Maybe try with Chrome, which has better dev tools?

Comment: @ShadowWizard response headers in Chrome tools are `Age:76476
Cache-Control:max-age=604800
Connection:keep-alive
Date:Wed, 24 Aug 2016 13:10:30 GMT
ETag:"e655cb848fdd11:0"
Vary:Accept-Encoding
Via:1.1 varnish
X-Cache:HIT
X-Cache-Hits:15041
X-Served-By:cache-bma7031-BMA
X-Timer:S1472044230.934409,VS0,VE0`

Comment: The crucial headers are Content-Length and Last-Modified, what are they in Chrome? (should be 64518 and Tue, 23 Aug 2016 15:54:02 GMT)

Comment: @ShadowWizard these appeared only after hard reload, `Content-Length:64393` and `Last-Modified:Tue, 23 Aug 2016 14:14:53 GMT`

Comment: Huh! So you're being served a different Sprites, while the CSS which contain the positions is new. This explains the mis-position. I'm afraid the only solution is for a dev to purge that varnish.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Yep, it's the same issue... see my answer/comments on the dupe.

Comment: @AdamLear you probably already know that but just in case, I just re-checked and the issue appears gone: every icon at every place where I reported these as messed up, looks okay now

Comment: @gnat Excellent, thanks for confirming.

Comment: @Adam thanks, though I still don't get what's going on with that Varnish cache.

Comment: @shadowwizard: it seems you're deploying code before assets. The first hit to the new code before the new assets are deployed makes the old sprite get cached with the new version tag. Change your deploy order.

Comment: @Quassnoi I'm not SE developer, just ordinary user like you, baffled by mysterious caches. (Or did you mean to ping Adam?)