# Site icons jumbled up

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

Some icons are correct, and some are whack. Turns out it's not just the hot questions list, but the whole icon set.

[image][image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: Normal day on meta. Yay! Devs breaking site icons, and people reporting it. :P

Comment: This is what I call teamwork. Long live SE!

Comment: I think [this just happened again last night.](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13556/site-icons-being-messed-up)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I knew I was forgetting something after a new private beta launch earlier today... Apparently that "something" was kicking the CDN cache on favicon sprites. Sorry about that.

The relevant files have been kicked now. Please let me know if the problem persists.

Comment: issue in profile page [reported in duplicate here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/283801/165773) seems to persist for me, does one need to wait for changes to propagate to verify the fix?

Comment: @gnat Hmm. Shouldn't need to, assuming I did the purge correctly (which isn't a given - it's my first time). Try a hard refresh locally? If that doesn't help, I'll kick it harder in the morning.

Comment: I did hard refresh before making prior comment :)

Comment: Fair enough. :) Kicking it harder in the morning it is, then, assuming someone in Europe doesn't beat me to it.

Comment: just in case if this may somehow help, the [profile](http://stackoverflow.com/users/811/shog9) I used to reproduce the issue over there shows me correct icons at MSE and MSO but wrong ones at Programmers, Programmers meta, and Stack Overflow

Comment: FWIW the issue is still there to me and I [managed to reproduce it from different computer and provider](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/283801/icons-for-some-sites-look-like-messed-up-in-user-profile?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment920048_283801)

Comment: So every time a new private beta is launched we should start new bug report to remind you to kick the cache? :-)

Comment: I get the right icons now, after clearing my cache.

Comment: I think [this just happened again last night.](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13556/site-icons-being-messed-up)